# erlang lager trace configuration

Tags: logging, erlang

I have issues with lager tracing feature.
What I need:

5 files:
1. **crash.log** - this is default lager file, let it be
2. **error.log** - here will be all errors and above
3. **info.log** - here will be all info, notice and warning messages
4&5. **transmitted.log** and **received.log** - here will be special messages with various severity using `lager:info([{type, tx}]` or `lager:error([{type, rx}]` and tracing feature.
Messages filtered to those files shouldn't duplicate in info.log and error.log

**what I've achieved so far:**
messages successfully redirect to transmitted and received log files, and error.log works as it should.

**problems:**
1. no idea how to make info.log accept only notice, info and warnings, without debug level (using `{level, '<error'}` will also include debug level)
2. messages redirected to transmitted.log and received.log files also appear in info.log and error.log files. 
f.e. if i use `lager:error([{type, tx}], "ERROR")` it appears 3x times: in info.log, error.log and transmitted.log, while it should appear only in transmitted.log

my lager config:

```
{lager, [
  {crash_log, 'logs/crash.log'}
  ,{handlers, [
    {lager_file_backend, [{file, "logs/info.log"}, {level, info}]}
    ,{lager_file_backend, [{file, "logs/error.log"}, {level, error}]}
    ,{lager_file_backend, [{file, "logs/received.log"}, {level, none}, {date, "$D0"},
      {formatter_config, [date, " ", time," [",severity,"] ", pid, " ", message, "\n"]}]}
    ,{lager_file_backend, [{file, "logs/transmitted.log"}, {level, none}, {date, "$D0"},
      {formatter_config, [date, " ", time," [",severity,"] ", pid, " ", message, "\n"]}]}
  ]}
  ,{traces, [
    {{lager_file_backend, "logs/received.log"}, [{type, rx}], info}
   ,{{lager_file_backend, "logs/transmitted.log"}, [{type, tx}], info}
  ]}
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1, please look at the lager's source file lager_util.erl

```
levels() ->
    [debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, alert, emergency, none].

level_to_num(debug)     -> ?DEBUG;
level_to_num(info)      -> ?INFO;
level_to_num(notice)    -> ?NOTICE;
level_to_num(warning)   -> ?WARNING;
level_to_num(error)     -> ?ERROR;
level_to_num(critical)  -> ?CRITICAL;
level_to_num(alert)     -> ?ALERT;
level_to_num(emergency) -> ?EMERGENCY;
level_to_num(none)      -> ?LOG_NONE.
```

DEBUG's the lowest level, If you need only log above NOTICE, just set as {level,notice}.

For the second problem, There are two methods.
1. I think you could solve it by add a new lager's backend. In the source code of lager's lager_file_backend.erl

```
handle_event({log, Message},
    #state{name=Name, level=L,formatter=Formatter,formatter_config=FormatConfig} = State) ->
    case lager_util:is_loggable(Message,L,{lager_file_backend, Name}) of
        true ->
            {ok,write(State, lager_msg:timestamp(Message), lager_msg:severity_as_int(Message), Formatter:format(Message,FormatConfig)) };
        false ->
            {ok, State}
    end;
```

You could created a new backend based on lager_file_backend and add your logical here to solve the problem.

Method 2. Not modify lager's source code, and use unix's bash and grep tools to solve the problem.